# Update using sub query not working

Tags: sql, h2

Am trying to execute the below update statement in H2

```
UPDATE table1
SET STATUS_CD = 1 
WHERE (col1, col2) 
IN (select col1, col2 FROM table2)
```

but it produces `Subquery is not a single column query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Exists`

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET STATUS_CD = 1 
WHERE exists (Select 1 FROM table2 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2)
```

Comment: it's updating all rows in table 1

Comment: Comment is unclear. Is that your intended result or not?

Comment: @fadytaher it means every record in col1 and col2 in `table1` is present in `table2`

Comment: @Pரதீப், actually it's only one record matching in both tables, but it's updating all rows instead in table 1